# Mapping MultiSelect Picklist values into Dropdown List in LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

I am trying to retrieve selected values of multivalued picklist from the Salesforce record and mapping them into a dropdown list of a LWC component. In order to retrieve, I have used wire adapters as below.

So far I can retrieve the prepopulated values on the salesforce records as semicolon separated values. eg:45;78;80. What I need is seperating those values and show them as dropdown values in my lwc component

```
 import {
    LightningElement,
    api,
    wire,
    track
} from 'lwc';
import {
    getObjectInfo,
    getPicklistValues
} from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import {
    getRecord,
    getFieldValue,
    getFieldDisplayValue
} from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import COURSE_ORDER1_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Course_Order__c';
import CREDIT_VALUES from '@salesforce/schema/Course_Order__c.Organization__r.Credit_Value__c';

const fields = [AC_SUBJECT_AREA, CREDIT_VALUES];


export default class lwcAssociations extends LightningElement {
    @api title = "LWC Association"
   
    @api credit_values = "Credit Value";
    @api button = "FINISH";

    @api recordId;
    @track value;
    @track credit_val_list=[];

    
    @wire(getObjectInfo,{objectApiName:COURSE_ORDER1_OBJECT})
    objectInfo;

    @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId', fieldApiName: CREDIT_VALUES})
    creditValues;


    get creditValues(){
        return getFieldValue(this.record.data,CREDIT_VALUES);
       
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.value = event.detail.value;
    }

    connectedCallback(){
        var credit_values = this.creditValues;
     
        this.credit_val_list = credit_values.split(',').map((fld) => fld.trim());
    }


}
```

Can someone help me splitting these values seperated by semiclons and map them into the picklist field in the template?

```
   <template>

    <div style="margin:20px; margin-bottom:150px; ">
        <lightning-card>

            <div>
                <header class="slds-modal__header">
                    <h6 id="modal-heading-06" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate"><b>{title}</b></h6>
                </header>
                <br />
                <!-- 1st row -->


                    <div class="oneline">
                        <template if:true={credit_val_list}>

                            <lightning-combobox label={creditValues} name="creditValue" value={value} options={credit_val_list}
                                onchange={handleChange}></lightning-combobox>
                        </template>

                    </div>
                    
           </div>

        </lightning-card>
    </div>

</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the **get creditValues()** as follows. After splitting the String seperated by commas, I pushed the resulting array into a new array.

```
 get creditValues() {
        var credit;
        var credit_val_list = [];
        credit = getFieldValue(this.record.data, CREDIT_VALUES);
        credit_val_list = String(abcd).split(";");
        console.log("Credit val" + credit_val_list);

        var i;
        var options = [];
        for (i = 0; i < credit_val_list.length; i++) {
            var item = {
                label: credit_val_list[i],
                value: credit_val_list[i]
            };
            options.push(item)

        }
        return options;


    }
```

Answer (score 3):

`lightning-combobox` does not support multiselect. You'll have to use `lightning-dual-listbox`

Also, the correct way to pass options to a `lightning-combobox` or `lightning-dual-listbox` is to pass list of objects with `value` and `label` property.

Markup -

```
<lightning-dual-listbox options={options}></lightning-dual-listbox>
```

JS -

```
 export default class LwcAssociations extends LightningElement {

    @track
    options = [
        { label: 'English', value: 'en' },
        { label: 'German', value: 'de' },
        { label: 'Spanish', value: 'es' }
    ]

 }
```

Comment: I am retrieving multipicklist values from salesforce record using wire adapters and just wanna display them in a dropdown. Actually want to map the retrieved data into dropdown

Comment: What will be the return value of wire adapter? A comma separated values?

Comment: semi colon seperated values

Comment: Ok, help me understand. So, is it something like, you need to display a multiselect picklist field with values prepopulated based on a record's values?

Comment: You are correct. Those prepopulated values can be retrieved by wire adapter with the help of  get credit2Values() as values seperated by semicolons. Eg: 45;78;65. These returns values are just prepopulated on the salesforce record. So what I need is showing those values on the combo box as dropdown values in my lwc component.

Comment: Replace `this.creditValues.split(';')` with `this.creditValues.split(';').map(val => {label:val,value: val})`. Also, set `options` attribute to `{credit_val_list} `. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working

Comment: Can you please update your question with whatever code you have right now? Please include the HTML file content as well.

Comment: Updated the question with the codes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118592/discussion-between-ruklani-attanyake-and-jay-rathod).